# using variables inside string in shell-script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My variable is not getting replaced by its value in shell-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter uuid "  uuid
read -p "Enter date in format yyyymmdd: " date

echo $uuid
echo $date

a=`zgrep 'Queue for uuid $uuid' reader_$date.gz`    
b=`zgrep 'Queue for uuid 23fef66b-fcf0-4a71-8ca3-a0761dffc473' reader_$date.gz`

echo $a
echo $b
```

output:

```
Enter uuid 23fef66b-fcf0-4a71-8ca3-a0761dffc473                                         
Enter date in format yyyymmdd: 20180323
23fef66b-fcf0-4a71-8ca3-a0761dffc473
20180323

[2018-03-23 17:27:10,535: INFO/Worker-1 None None tasks/push_to_rabbit] Queue for uuid 23fef66b-fcf0-4a71-8ca3-a0761dffc473 is 35.154.190.22_2_k_event
```

Why is variable `a` empty?

Comment: Just in passing, did you mean `yyyymmdd` (4-digit year) as your example input suggests, rather than a 3-digit year as written in the prompt?

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `reader_$date.gz`, it's hard to tell.  But your first `zgrep` command searches for `Queue uuid for` where the second has `Queue for uuid`.  Did you accidentally swap the order of those words?

Comment: @TobySpeight that was typo error. edited code to correct it.

Comment: And did fixing the typo make your code work?  If not, then please create a [mcve] - that means something the rest of us can *replicate* without needing your input files.

Comment: Actually, it won't have fixed the problem, because you used single quotes around `$uuid` where you wanted double quotes (so that the parameter could be expanded).

Comment: Try this. It should be working as @TobySpeight suggested. a=`zgrep "Queue for uuid $uuid" reader_$date.gz`
b=`zgrep 'Queue for uuid 23fef66b-fcf0-4a71-8ca3-a0761dffc473' reader_$date.gz`

Comment: Just tried and working fine for me. Replace with double quotes to allow expansion of variable.

Comment: @vishnunarayanan thanks it is working. replacing single quote with double quote. worked.Now variable a has same value as b

Comment: @gouravkumar Great.

Comment: For your future convenience, [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically detected [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2016).

Answer (score 3):

You need double-quotes where parameters should be expanded, not single-quotes.

Wrong quotation:

```
u=23; d=3; a=$(zgrep 'Mar $u 23' /var/log/syslog.$d.gz); echo $a
```

Right quotation:

```
u=23; d=3; a=$(zgrep "Mar $u 23" /var/log/syslog.$d.gz); echo $a
Mar 23 23:00:01 tux201t CRON[25808]: (stefan) CMD ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace single quotes with double quotes to allow for bash variable substitution.

From

```
a=`zgrep 'Queue for uuid $uuid' reader_$date.gz`
```

To

```
a=`zgrep "Queue for uuid $uuid" reader_$date.gz`
```